# Filtering State Logic in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to filter my state (array of objects) based on an input value but I am pretty sure I am doing something very wrong and violating a core concept/rule in React. It is filtering my state when I am typing, however, If I want to get back to the original state (input value is empty), I cannot because I already mutated the array? I am trying to copy the original state to another array and process it, but the result is the same.

What is the correct way to filter the state based on this example?

```
const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '040-123456' },
    { name: 'Ada Lovelace', number: '39-44-5323523' },
    { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', number: '39-23-6423122' }
  ]);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');


  const handleFilterName = event => {
    setName(event.target.value);
    if (name !== '') {
      const filteredPersons = persons.filter(person =>
        person.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())
      );
      setPersons(filteredPersons);
    }
  };

...

 return (
      <div>
        Filter: <input onChange={handleFilterName} value={name} />
      </div>
...
```

Comment: Keep a separate reference, e.g. originalPeople.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably write it like this:

1. `handleFilterName` only sets the name.
2. When you are going to show the filtered list, at that point (e.g. in the `render`), calculate `filteredPersons` and show them. Do not alter the `persons` list.
3. Then, if you reset name, you will still have your full list.

This is a working example:

```js
function App() {
  const persons = [
    { name: "Arto Hellas", number: "040-123456" },
    { name: "Ada Lovelace", number: "39-44-5323523" },
    { name: "Mary Poppendieck", number: "39-23-6423122" }
  ];
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const handleFilterName = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  const filteredPersons =
    name === ""
      ? persons
      : persons.filter(person =>
          person.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())
        );

  return (
    <div>
      Filter: <input onChange={handleFilterName} value={name} />
      <ul>
        {filteredPersons.map(person => (
          <li>
            {person.name}: {person.number}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you think this is the best way based on your experience?

Comment: Yes, I'd say this is normal practice. You could refactor it by extracting the person list into a separate component that took the name as a parameter.